# file format not recognized; treating as linker script. Error in text file?

Tags: c++, linux

I am running ubuntu, linux. I am trying to compile three files, a main.cpp and Token.h and Token.cpp files. I am trying to read in from a file called test1 that is a text file. Here is my input to the terminal

```
g++ test1 -std=c++11 main.cpp token.cpp token.h -Wall -o myprog
```

I get the following error-

```
/usr/bin/ld:test1: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:test1:2: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I got rid of all the data in my main to make sure it wasn't that.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to read in from a file called test1 that is a text file.

Do you think that if you pass it to g++ you'll read from it? Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

To build your program try to use this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp token.cpp -Wall -o myprog
```

[g++](http://www.cprogramming.com/g++.html) is the C++ compiler, it compiles/links your c++ code into executable programs. Once your program is compiled by `g++` you can execute it and pass your file name to the program (assuming that your file is called `test1`):

```
./myprog test1
```

Comment: So, I put that text file specifically there because in the code, I have the following format...          int main(int argc, char* argv[]). String created called token_file. and Then "token_file = argv[1]"; I am simply trying to compile these all together and read from that text file.

Comment: @user280339 and then you fopen (or use fstream) to read from token_file?

Comment: @user280339 check updated answer. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: That is it! Forgot some simple order guidelines. Thank you!